# Understanding twitter streaming api response

Tags: twitter, tweepy

I am not a very avid user and hence having a hard time figuring out what each field means in twitter api response. Going thru documentation has only resulted in me going in circles.

What I am trying to do is analyzing how things go viral. So, what I did was grabbed data from twitter streaming api with hope of analyzing the response but I am totally confused.
So a sample json response is :

```
{"created_at":"Thu Mar 14 18:19:12 +0000 2013","id":312266679390457857,"id_str":"312266679390457857","text":"The first four winners of our March Madness Giveaway (4x ADATA Technology (USA) 16GB DashDrives) are:\n\nAaron... http:\/\/t.co\/ikPbfRZQdq","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/twitter\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eFacebook\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":179622147,"id_str":"179622147","name":"Levetron","screen_name":"Levetron","location":"Los Angeles","url":"http:\/\/www.aziocorp.com","description":"Official Twitter for Levetron by AZiO. Here for customer questions, gaming tips & tricks, sharing cool ideas, product launch releases, reviews and more!","protected":false,"followers_count":1042,"friends_count":25,"listed_count":4,"created_at":"Tue Aug 17 18:56:29 +0000 2010","favourites_count":5,"utc_offset":-28800,"time_zone":"Pacific Time (US & Canada)","geo_enabled":false,"verified":false,"statuses_count":707,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"131516","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/images\/themes\/theme14\/bg.gif","profile_background_tile":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/a0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3223061028\/999ac6efc782d85983cbcf7f2deab7c1_normal.png","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_images\/3223061028\/999ac6efc782d85983cbcf7f2deab7c1_normal.png","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/si0.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/179622147\/1360294489","profile_link_color":"009999","profile_sidebar_border_color":"EEEEEE","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"EFEFEF","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweet_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"http:\/\/t.co\/ikPbfRZQdq","expanded_url":"http:\/\/fb.me\/M6YPCk9W","display_url":"fb.me\/M6YPCk9W","indices":[112,134]}],"user_mentions":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"medium"}
```

1)My guess is if this tweet is a result of a retweet then "retweeted" should be true.
But how do i figure out from which user it was retweeted?
2) Is "id" user id or tweet id?

Basically, if lets say I want to analyze how (say) Gangham style went viral.. who retweeted/followed that particular tweet, how should i do this?

Also, has twitter recently changed its api. I am using python for this but looks to me that all of those api's examples are not working

```
For example: https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy
```

Any suggestions.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the Twitter API [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object) relating to tweets. It describes all parameters returned in the Twitter JSON response.

That tweet was not retweeted because `retweeted` is set to false and `retweeted_count` is 0.

From the documentation:

> id = The integer representation of the unique identifier for this
>   Tweet.
>
> Retweets can be distinguished from typical Tweets by the existence of
>   a retweeted_status attribute. This attribute contains a representation
>   of the original Tweet that was retweeted.

Also, [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/developer-utilities/twitter-libraries) is a list of supported twitter libraries. There are several other libraries other than tweepy listed that might work for you.

Comment: Link no longer valid